# JsResultException - unable to successfully parse json - 2.4x Play Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following case class;

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Dose (date: Timestamp, ptHospitalNumber: String)
```

and in my controller the following code to handle the json;

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit val doseReads: Reads[Dose] = (
    (JsPath \ "date").read[Long].map(long => new Timestamp(long)) and
    (JsPath \ "ptHospitalNumber").read[String]
  )(Dose.apply _)

  def addDoses() = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
    val doses = (request.body \ "doses" ).as[List[Dose]]
    //then iterate through the list and return json response
  }
```

However, when the json is sent (from an Android device as a List[Dose] using  org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter), I keep getting this error;

> play.api.libs.json.JsResultException:  JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List([{"date":1445789736831,
>   "hospitalNumber":"A059ES21"},{"date":1445790530290,"hospitalNumber":"A059ES21"}] is not an object),WrappedArray())))))

I also tried the following but it returned null;

```
    val dosesJsResult = (request.body \ "doses" ).validate[List[Dose]]
    val doses = dosesJsResult match{
      case s: JsSuccess[List[Dose]] => s.get
      case e: JsError => null
    }
```

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Looks like your `request.body \ "doses"` is array of arrays and not just the array in JSON. Can we see the request?

Comment: Hi, I can't figure out a way to view the request. The json is sent from an Android device according to user input, so there is no url to request it for me to view. Are there any other ways I could view the request? I've searched for the past hour but can't figure out how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to find a list called "doses" in the json, but that didn't exist. All I needed to do was parse the request body as a List of Dose;

```
implicit val doseDataReads = new Reads[Dose] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Dose] = {
    val date = (json \ "date").as[Long]
    val hospitalNumber = (json \ "hospitalNumber").as[String]
    JsSuccess(Dose(hospitalNumber, new Timestamp(date)))
  }
}

def addDoses() = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
    val doses = request.body.as[List[Dose]]
    //rest of code to persist doses etc
}
```